# echo mysql select statement with wpdb displays NO RESULTS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

**I would like this function in my plugin to return data when it's called for**. I'm just trying to get any result back at this point. It used to be a more specific query.

```
function ml_results() {
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_ml_char', OBJECT );
echo "<p>Your character's info {$results}</p>";
}

add_shortcode('ml_return', 'ml_results');
```

I've had no luck returning and displaying ANYTHING with any output_type. I've also tried print instead of echo. I've also tested my query in phpmyadmin which works just fine. All I get returned is "ARRAY". So, $results returns "Your character's info  ARRAY". Var_dump also works just fine, but that's not specifically how I would like my data displayed. So I belive the problem lies in the Wordpress code, but I'm just not sure what part of the code exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are returned in array, that is why, they can't be printed out as a string. Actually, you have set flag OBJECT, and results are being returned as object, containing field values for all records in wp_ml_char table. 
You should try something like this:

```
function ml_results() {
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_ml_char', OBJECT );
$output = '';
foreach($results as $item){
//and then for each field in wp_ml_char table you want to set in output should append to $output var: 
$output.= $item->field_name . " ";  // field_name should be changed to name of actual field in wp_ml_char table

}
echo "<p>Your character's info {$output}</p>";

}

add_shortcode('ml_return', 'ml_results');
```

One other thing that bothers me is actual MySQL statement, where you haven't defined more precise condition, and this query you have now as it is, would return all results from wp_ml_char table, so you should add some condition also and probably some limit and offset.

Comment: This works beautifully, and it's exactly what I wanted. I'm just trying to understand why the $output variable itself needs to be appended like that. It works fine without being appended too. Anyway, thank you very much Niklaz you've been a huge help!

Comment: @CodyTetreault, glad that it helped :). About $output, you can pass db record values whatever you like, I gave you just an example. For example, you just want to pass only one field. 
In that case you don't need to append value. 
But in case when you have two or more fields that you want to output in sequence, one of ways to do this is like in example. 
I.E. `$output.= $item->title . " " . $item->content; `
or `$output.= $item->title; 
$output.= $item-> content; `